# What's happening with the snippet below in a release build?

Tags: c++

The code below generates a dangling reference as can be seen in the warning emitted by the compiler and the fact that the destructor for the `A` object in function `g()` is invoked before the function returns. One can also verify that in `main()` after "using the stack", the returned reference has garbage, at least in a debug build. But I couldn't reproduce the same behavior in a release build. Why is that? What kind of optimization the compiler is doing here to give the impression that the reference `r` is Ok?

```
#include <iostream>

struct A{
    A(int i) : i(i) { std::cout << "Ctor\n"; }
    A(const A& a) { i = a.i; std::cout << "Copy ctor\n"; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "Dtor\n"; }
    int i;
};

A& g(int i) { A x(i); return x; }

int main()
{
    const A& r = g(1);
    std::cout << "Using the stack\n";     
    std::cout << r.i << '\n';   // r.i has garbage in debug, but not in a release build.
}
```

PS. I would argue against NRVO, as the function doesn't return an `A` object.

**Edit: In response to Mark Tolonen. Even if I include these expressions after `const A& r = g(1);` the release build doesn't show garbage in `std::cout << r.i << '\n';`**

```
std::cout << "Using the stack ...................................................................................................................\n";
std::cout << "Using the stack ...................................................................................................................\n";
std::cout << "Using the stack ...................................................................................................................\n";
std::cout << "Using the stack ...................................................................................................................\n";
```

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined... (outputs 1 for me in both release and debug)

Comment: Checked disassembly. It's optimized, either in register or use immediate.

Comment: @Immueggpain AFAIK VS2010 allows disassembly only in debug builds.

Comment: @user1162978 huh? What gave you that idea? And what does "allow disassembly only in release builds" even mean?

Comment: @NikBougalis See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3cwf295.aspx under "To display disassembly window"

Comment: @user1162978, for that matter, you can do anything in release build you can do in debug build (source debug, set breakpoints, etc) its just with optimized code it is more difficult.  A function might be inlined in multiple places and not have *one* place to set a breakpoint, for example.

Comment: Slightly related, I recommend reading Herb Sutter's [A Candidate For the Most Important const](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what the speed-optimized (/O2 compiler switch) release build of Visual Studio 2012 64-bit actually does when it runs this code and prints out a one:

```
int main()
{
000000013F7C7E50  sub         rsp,28h  
    const A& r = g(1);
000000013F7C7E54  lea         rdx,[string "Ctor\n" (013F83DA4Ch)]  
000000013F7C7E5B  lea         rcx,[std::cout (013F85FAA0h)]  
000000013F7C7E62  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (013F7C1500h)  
000000013F7C7E67  lea         rdx,[string "Dtor\n" (013F83DA54h)]  
000000013F7C7E6E  lea         rcx,[std::cout (013F85FAA0h)]  
000000013F7C7E75  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (013F7C1500h)  
    std::cout << "Using the stack\n";     
000000013F7C7E7A  lea         rdx,[string "Using the stack\n" (013F83DA60h)]  
000000013F7C7E81  lea         rcx,[std::cout (013F85FAA0h)]  
000000013F7C7E88  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (013F7C1500h)  
    std::cout << r.i << '\n';   // r.i has garbage in debug, but not in a release build.
000000013F7C7E8D  lea         rcx,[std::cout (013F85FAA0h)]  
000000013F7C7E94  mov         edx,1  
000000013F7C7E99  call        std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (013F7C1384h)  
000000013F7C7E9E  mov         dl,0Ah  
000000013F7C7EA0  mov         rcx,rax  
000000013F7C7EA3  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (013F7C10EBh)
```

Note that it doesn't even bother to really create and destroy the `A` object.  All it does is call `cout` four times.  Each time, `rdx` holds the object to print.  The first three print the strings "Ctor\n", "Dtor\n", and "Using the stack\n".  The last one looks like it just prints the integer in `edx` which is a `1`.

The compiler can really do anything for undefined behavior.  It prints something besides a one for space-optimized (/O1 compiler switch), or as the OP found, not-optimized (/Od).

Answer (score 11):

It's just undefined behavior. You return a temporary by reference, anything can happen.

The `A& g(int i) { A x(i); return x; }` is illegal.

A debug build will probably clear the memory and cause errors because the memory was cleared.

A release build doesn't bother. You pay for what you use, right? It just leaves the memory untouched, but marks it as reclaimable by the OS. All gloves are off afterwards.

It's an (arguably) good thing that comes with the VC++ compiler. You'll see all sort of stuff happening in debug build to help you... well... debug better. Uninitialized pointers set to some specific value so that you *know* it's uninitialized, memory zeroed out after a `delete` so that you *know* it was deleted. This helps in identifying problems sooner, because in a release build you'd probably still see the memory if it wasn't overwritten, or access an uninitialized pointer and have it *appear* to work, etc. Problems you wouldn't see otherwise, and at the time you would spot would cause a lot of harm and would be very hard to diagnose.

Comment: @Elazar UB says *anything* is allowed to happen. I explained why (attempted to at least), but there's little to no point in reasoning about UB. Just avoid it.

Comment: This explanation is what I've asked for. +1

Comment: Could you give the clause in the Standard that says this is illegal. I know it is, but I'm just being curious. Thanks.

Comment: @user1162978 feeling kinda lazy, it's in there :)

Comment: @user1162978 `3.8 Object Lifetime`

Comment: @LuchianGrigore `A release build doesn't bother. You pay for what you use, right? It just leaves the memory untouched, but marks it as reclaimable by the OS. All gloves are off afterwards.` And that's exactly the situation where the last expression in main() above should have printed garbage, after the stack was used. How come it continues printing the correct number?

Comment: @user1162978: If it made sense to describe the behavior the standard would do so.  It does not make sense because the code does not make sense, so it is simply "undefined"

Comment: @user1162978 in a release build, the compiler doesn't clear the memory. So it's still there. So it appears to work. Regardless of the explanation, it's still illegal.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore But shouldn't it be reclaimed by the OS (from the stack) for executing `std::cout << "Using the stack\n";`? That's what I don't understand.

Comment: @user1162978, if you want to understand it, disassemble it.  The behavior is **undefined** so only looking at what the compiler you are using generated for machine code will help you understand.  What likely happened is `std::cout << "Using the stack\n"` didn't overwrite enough of the stack to clobber the value.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I don't think I can disassembly the code in release build. `What likely happened is std::cout << "Using the stack\n" didn't overwrite enough of the stack to clobber the value.`See my edit in the question.

Comment: @user1162978 I have checked. It's using an immediate. And if the value can be different, it's using a register. That's on VC2010.

Comment: @user1162978 you can disassemble release code just fine - it may just be trickier since its more heavily optimized. And no, it's not *required* that the stack be used - there are alternatives. Perhaps the compiler decided it was more efficient to allocate extra stack space and release all of it at a later time, or to use a register, or to do any number of things. All perfectly valid and perfectly compliant with the standard as long as it guarantees the correct behavior of a program that doesn't exhibit undefined behavior, like the one you show here.

Comment: @NikBougalis The truth of the matter is, I didn't know up to this point that I could debug a release build. I guess I have never tried the F5 key in a release build. Many thanks for calling my attention to this